# MVC DropdownlistFor set selected value not working?c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using this code to set selected value

```
foreach (var item in clsObj.Branch_SName)
{
    if (item.Value.Split('|')[5] == Session["Branch_ID"].ToString())
    {
        item.Selected = true;  //debugger comes here ok but not set value as selected 
        break;
    }
}
```

but I return view return View

```
return View(clsObj);
```

that bind drop down as

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Branch_Code, Model.Branch_SName)
```

but not set selected value when I debug the model select list where returning `clsObj.Branch_SName` have no selected value. Why also tell me dropdown list change event?

Comment: Its the value of `Branch_Code` that determines what is selected (that is how model binding works) - setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored when binding to a property. If it matches one of your option values, then that option will be selected.

Comment: have you not seen debugger there i write yes value matched but problem is it wont set selected value

Comment: What does that have to do with anything. Did you read my comment (setting the `Selected` value is ignored!)

Comment: So how should i select the selected value `clsObj.Branch_SName.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Value.Split('|')[5] ==   Session["pUser_Branch_ID"].ToString());`

Comment: I don't know what your values are. You need to set the value of `Branch_Code` to match one of the option values in the GET method before you pass the model to the view.

Comment: take any value suppose value is `1|A ,2|B ,3|C` AND you   have  `B` so `split(2|B)[1] == B` SELECT this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151683/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-nouman-arshad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can set a value in Branch_Code, which will be bound to the model as selected value.  So you need to do it like this.

```
clsObj.Branch_Code= selectedBranCode; //You need to perform filter operation from your collection.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<SelectListItem> lst = GENERIC.ToSelectListItem(ds_1.Tables[0], "Branch_SName", "Branch_Code"); 

var selected = lst.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Value.Split('|')[5] == Session["pUser_Branch_ID"].ToString()); 

selected.Selected = true; //important
clsObj.Branch_SName = new SelectList(lst, "Value", "Text", selected); //important
clsObj.Branch_Code = selected.Value;//important
```

This works selecting branch code and selected true